# I can't create controller in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: entity

I want create controller in mvc 4 (vs 2012)

"MVC controller with read/write action and view using Entity Framwork"

But I can't choose my model class.

my model class

```
 public class Authorss
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name{get;set;}
    }
    public class ModelContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet Authors { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I decided this problem. When I create model class, I don't rebuild my project and when I want to choose model class, it was don't visible.